# Error when running applet with Slick2D

Tags: java, applet, slick2d

I have been trying to get a slick application to work on a website for awhile now, and I have the HTML code correct, I know that for sure, however I am getting an error from the applet saying this:

```
Initializing real applet
Mon May 20 17:07:24 EDT 2013 ERROR:Game.GameBoard
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Game.GameBoard
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppletGameContainer.init(AppletGameContainer.java:123)
at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.switchApplet(AppletLoader.java:1330)
at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader$2.run(AppletLoader.java:909)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
This occurred while 'Initializing real applet'
Unable to create game container
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create game container
at org.newdawn.slick.AppletGameContainer.init(AppletGameContainer.java:147)
at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.switchApplet(AppletLoader.java:1330)
at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader$2.run(AppletLoader.java:909)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Done loading
```

I understand that the applet won't start. I've done some excessive searching to find the answer, however, I have found none. I do not use a GameState, but use a BasicGame. Most tutorials I've read say to just write it like a normal application. So I'm confused as to how to get this to work properly. It doesn't seem like I need to make any new changes, but that I can't figure out what exactly I need to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: *"Most tutorials I've read say to just write it like a normal application."*  In that case. abandon the applet.  For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to launch the app. from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The reason it says to "Write like a normal application" is because the HTML file takes care of the proper steps and communicates with the applet in order to run it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if the error happened as a naming issue.